# How can I map from to sources to the same object in ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

How can I express the following in ModelMapper: To fill a field in the target, I want to use property A of the source if it is non-null, otherwise use the property B.

Example (Code below if you don't like technical descriptions):
Let's say I want from a source class `SourceBigThing` to a target class `Target` using ModelMapper. The `SourceBigThing` has two properties, one called `red` and one called `green`. These two properties are of different types `RedSmallThing` and `GreenSmallThing`. Both of these things have a property called `name`. A `SourceBigThing` can either have a red or a green, but not both (the other is null). I want to map the names of the Small Things to a property of the target-class.

Example-Code:

```
class SourceBigThing {
    private final SourceSmallThingGreen green;
    private final SourceSmallThingRed red;
}

class SourceSmallThingGreen {
    private final String name;
}

class SourceSmallThingRed {
    private final String name;
}



class Target {
    private TargetColorThing thing;
}

class TargetColorThing {
    // This property should either be "green.name" or "red.name" depending
    // on if red or green are !=null
    private String name; 
}
```

I tried to play around with the conditionals, but you cannot have two mappings to the same target because ModelMapper throws an exception for duplicate mappings:

```
when(Conditions.isNotNull()).map(source.getGreen()).setThing(null);
when(Conditions.isNotNull()).map(source.getRed()).setThing(null);
```

You can find a failing TestNG-Unit-Test at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/474dcc4a86cd375ea321#file-modelmapper-multi-map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of an unusual case, so there's no neat way of doing this. But you can always use a Converter - something like:

```
using(new Converter<SourceBigThing, TargetColorThing>(){
  public TargetColorThing convert(MappingContext<SourceBigThing, TargetColorThing> context) {
    TargetColorThing target = new TargetColorThing();
    if (context.getSource().getGreen() != null)
      target.setName(context.getSource().getGreen().getName());
    else if (context.getSource().getRed() != null)
      target.setName(context.getSource().getRed().getName());
    return target;
}}).map(source).setThing(null);
```